# Jquery: Get data from Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, object, jsonp

I start working with amazon "Keyword Suggestion" web service.

I get the data using ajax and dataType: 'jsonp'

I want to get the data saved in object 0 array "nodes" -> name and alias but i dont know how to get this data.

Here is the example of the output

Example:
http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?method=completion&q=lg%20g4%2032&search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&x=updateISSCompletion&sc=1&noCacheIE=1294493634389

The output is:

[image]

Comment: That isn't jsonp or json output. You need to research their docs more

Comment: @charlietfl i have update my question

Comment: Go through linked answer/tutorial. If you run into problems you will need to be a lot more specific and post actual code